# Change the top customer menu

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I have this shop:
http://tienda.mabaonline.com/en/
And I want to know how I can translate some strings in the spanish page:
http://tienda.mabaonline.com/es like "My menu" -> "Mi menu"  "Shopping bag"->"Carrito de compra"
I'll try writing in a translate.csv file but it doesn't work.

any idea?

Comment: Which csv file are you editing? You will have to check your locale first in `System > Configuration > General > Locale Options` and edit that locale file for your specific store.

Comment: Sorry but, which file? I don't have any file in Locale Options

Answer (score 0):

Add a string to file translate.csv in Your theme.
This file must be on Your theme.
For examle:
    `app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/es_ES/translate.csv`
`app/design/frontend/ves_styleshop/locale/es_ES/transalte.csv`

At the end of this file (If you do not have him copy it out 
`app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US)` add string "My Menu","translate text"

Comment: Yes I did it, but it doesn't work, I clean the cache after upload the file but nothing happened

Comment: In this case, the error in the Theme.
Otherwise, the translations used in this order:
/app/locale
/app/design/frontend/theme
online transaction

Try to find the "Menu" in the Theme and see if it looks like <? Php echo $ this -> __ ('Menu'); ?>

Comment: Sorry, in which file I have to find this?

Comment: That is a question. Try to search Template package to the string "menu".
In rwd template is: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

Comment: I have in a file called top.menu.phtml `<?php echo $_menu ?>`

Comment: But I can't find a string "menu" in any file :S

Comment: Nnn. $_menu is a variable. You must find string "menu" resp. "My Menu".

Comment: I'll find it, app/design/frontend/ves_style/default/template/page/template/links.phtml I just have to change it in this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24249/discussion-between-mimo-and-ali-atriple).

Comment: You must add the missing string "My Menu" to Mage_Page.csv